# Ajax not submitting data after validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I am using form validation plug-in ([formvalidation.io](http://formvalidation.io)) to validate the form fields. I am using ajax to submit data to another php file for processing. Validation is working fine, but the data is not submitted.

Following is my code:

```
$("#ajaxsubmit").formValidation({
          framework: 'bootstrap',
          excluded: ':disabled',
          message: 'This value is not valid',
          container: 'popover',
          trigger: 'blur',
          feedbackIcons: {
              valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
              invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
              validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
          },
          fields: {
             test: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                message: 'The field is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },

          },

}),
// Use Ajax to submit form data
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("submitbtn").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "test", _("test").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "process.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("ajaxsubmit").innerHTML = '<h4>Thanks '+_("test").value+', your request has been sent.</h4>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("submitbtn").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
```

Below is my form

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="ajaxsubmit" id="ajaxsubmit" >
    <input name="test" id="test" class="form-control" type="text" required><br></br>
    <input name="submitbtn" type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitForm(); return false;"><br></br>
    <span id="status"></span></br>
</form>
```

If I disable the validation, the data is submitted.

Something is wrong but not able to catch it up. Can any one help me?

Comment: did you went possible error list? http://formvalidation.io/examples/cant-submit-form-after-validation/

Comment: Checked the link, but none of the error in the link is related to my issue.

Comment: you mean, if validation is enabled, the ajax doesn't run at all? Or you mean you don't get a 200 response back from the server? Because you're not checking for any other response - maybe there's something in your console or network tab.

Comment: Getting error  in Console  :  
    Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at submitForm ((index):84)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):30)

Comment: what is the _? is it meant to be a shorthand for a library, a bit like $ is for jQuery? I've never seen that before. Anyway the error is saying it doesn't know what  _ means. Your line numbers are different to the sample but I'd guess it's `_("submitbtn")` that's the issue.

Comment: its custom function : function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }

Comment: oh yes I see. The end of the `$("#ajaxsubmit").formValidation({` function closes with `}),`. Pretty sure it should be `});`. Try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom ajax code was the culprit. I switched to jquery .ajax() and now everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The end of the

```
$("#ajaxsubmit").formValidation({
```

function closes with

```
}),
```

Change it to

```
});
```

When you add this in with the comma, it's stopping your `function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }` from being interpreted correctly as a global function, which then causes the "not defined" error when you try to use it.

Comment: @abstract please define how "not working" exactly? "not working" is not an error message. Anyway, it works for me. Here's a simplified example, showing it not working when you use that syntax: https://jsfiddle.net/hdm9fnjy/ Check the console error when you click the submit button. Now here it is with my change in place, working perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/hdm9fnjy/1/ So something else must be happening in your code that affects it, or you haven't implemented it properly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, its throwing error : Uncaught ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):31). Line 31 is the button element in html code.

Comment: ok. If you have got submitForm inside some sort of jQuery "document.ready()" block, move it out of that (but ensure it occurs _before_ the button in the page), or remove the inline event handler and replace it with a jQuery style one (e.g. `$("#submitbtn").click(function()...` which contains the functionality which is currently in submitForm.

Comment: I moved the function submitForm before the form. Not it gets submitted but without validation. It now submits even blank form without validating. And console showing nothing.

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue? I can't reproduce your problem at all.